# using the onchange event with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list, when a user select a particular option (named Customize) using the onchange event then a div (with id of customizeOption) pops up and once the user is finished with the div he/she will click on a button (with id of donebtn). Is it good idea to have a function like this and using the onchange events? Any other suggestions are really appreciated.

```
function optionCheck(events) {

    if(events.value=="Customize") {
        $('document').ready(function () {
            $("#customizeOption").show(400);
            $("#donebtn").click(function () {
                $("#customizeOption").hide(400);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('document').ready(function () {});`

This is only to mimic the `onload` of the body.

We can rewrite the above code like.

```
function optionCheck(events) {
    if(events.value=="Customize") {
        $("#customizeOption").show(400);
        $("#donebtn").click(function () {
            $("#customizeOption").hide(400);
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure that you write this after the `DIV`s are rendered. And also they are available when your browser is compiling this JS. I recommend that this script should go in the bottom of the page.

---

**EDITED**

Assuming that the SELECT BOX has the class `mySelectBox`, The following function will work for you if you place it any where in the code.

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.mySelectBox').change(function(){
        if( $(this).attr('value')) == "Customize" ) {
            $("#customizeOption").show(400);
            $("#donebtn").click(function () {
                $("#customizeOption").hide(400);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. since this is a function, why did you suggest that it should go in the bottom of the page. as you know a function is only executes when it is called. at the moment i have this function in a js file and is included in the head of my document. thanks for your help again

Comment: on the `line#4` the statement `$("#donebtn")` is a JQuery function that will get the element of that `ID`. So if we place that query on the top of the page, the function would not be able to locate the element and will not bind the `click` function to the required element. In such cases we use `.live(eventType,handler)`

Comment: thanks so much for your replies. thats why initially i had all statements inside the document.ready() function. so as you know, these statements will only be exceuted is when all the dom objects were loaded. so in the case of our btn, binding the click function would locate the element. this is only if i leave the doucment.ready function as i initally posted. please correct me if im wrong. thanks

Comment: Hay, `document.ready()` should not be inside of any event of page. It will not execute until the event fire. so we always place it outside of any function.

Comment: the reason i don't want it that way, is because my js file is in header file. and the header file is included in all the files. so if do it that way then that piece of code will be executed every time the user goes from one page to other. thats why i had it inside a function which was executed only when that function was envoked. also i want to include all my javascript code into a single file, not on every file. again thanks for your help.